# Package creation Error

Tags: managed-package, package.xml, 2gp

I am trying to create a new version of the manage package and if i run the command

> sfdx force:package:version:create --package "PackageName" --wait 10 --codecoverage --installationkeybypass --loglevel trace

I am getting the following error

> Credentials__mdt.Token_URL__c: An object
> 'Credentials__mdt.Token_URL__c' of type CustomField was named
> in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

This error is repeated for all the fields of this Custom Metadata.
However, the custom metadata and the fields exist

> salesforce-managed-package git:(master)  ls force-app/main/default/objects/Credentials__mdt/fields
> Callback_URL__c.field-meta.xml  Client_ID__c.field-meta.xml     Client_Secret__c.field-meta.xml Scope__c.field-meta.xml         Token_URL__c.field-meta.xml

This manage package is already listed so this used to work. However, I am stumped about this issue now. I would appreciate some pointers on how to fix this.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Did you recently update your version of `sfdx`?

Comment: I might have. I am currently on the following version git:(master) ✗ sfdx
Salesforce CLI
VERSION
  sfdx-cli/7.175.0 darwin-x64 node-v18.12.0

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason to **not** use Named Credentials and have your own CMT covering credentials?

Comment: could you share folder structure in your project, and the package definition in sfdx file?

Comment: Hi @PhilW I have just picked up the maintenance of this app. However, I think the reason might be they/we are using a custom auth provider

Comment: Hi @Luisma, This is the package definition file. It has list of package aliases which I have removed.

  {
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": “PackageName”,
            "versionNumber": "1.6.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST"
        }
    ],
    "name": “packagename”,
    "namespace": "packagename",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "54.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "packagename": "0Ho8d000000wk4UCAQ"
    }
}

Comment: Please add detail requested by the community using [edit] on the question, not by adding comments. Thanks.